# Update another component on click

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to display a new string on the page when a button is clicked.  Right now I have a service being called that returns a string when I tap a button.  This works, I can alert and log the value and I'm getting what I want there.  However when I click the button, I want that value to be displayed on the page

This is what I have so far :

```
class Status extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>{this.props.status}</Text>
    );
  }
}

class StupidStatusApp extends Component {

  _onPressButton() {
      return fetch('http://stupidstat.us/api/user/status')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson.text);
        return responseJson.text;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Status status={this._onPressButton} style={styles.welcome}>
        </Status>
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={this._onPressButton}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Get new stupid status</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm not sure how to pass the value into  and re render every button click.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the status and trying to assign it to the property, you should store the status in a state and update it using `setState`. Then you can pass the state to your `Status` component:

```js
class Status extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>{this.props.status}</Text>
    );
  }
}

class StupidStatusApp extends Component {

  _onPressButton() {
      return fetch('http://stupidstat.us/api/user/status')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson.text);
        this.setState({status:responseJson.text}); // Change here 
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Status status={this.state.status //Change here} style={styles.welcome}>
        </Status>
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button} onPress={() => {this._onPressButton}}> // Change here
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Get new stupid status</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```